# Error 175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is not registered

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, edmx

*I know there are similar questions that have been asked, but most are related to Entity Framework or have been left unanswered. So please do not mark as Duplicate just by the title.*

I have an issue with a **VB.NET** application, following an upgrade of the users machine *(to Windows8 64-bit OS)*. 
In fact, when I open the source code to rebuild the application, I get the `Error 175` coming from the **edmx** file:

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is
>   either not registered in the machine or application config file, or
>   could not be loaded.

I checked a bit online but almost all the answers refers to Entity Framework.

`MySQL Connector 6.1.6` has been installed and the corresponding reference ***MySQL.data*** has been added, yet I cannot clear the error.

Error goes from this line of my edmx file, when the Provider is called;

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema Namespace="tci_db_01Model.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="5.1" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="db_01ModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="tb0001_nitg" EntityType="db_01Model.Store.tb0001_nitg" store:Type="Tables" Schema="db_02" />
```

*ConnectionString* in the **app.config** file is as follows;

```
</connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
      <DbProviderFactories>
        <clear />
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
      </DbProviderFactories> 
    </system.data>
```

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? How do I clear the error?

Comment: You keep saying that this is not related to EF but an EDMX file is the XML schema for an Entity Data Model, i.e. an Entity Framework model.  One of us is missing something here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney But there is no call to MySql.Data.Entity or MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.